# Nested structure padding - C - 64 bit - linux

Tags: c, 64-bit, nested, padding, structure

I have the following Nested structure in C. (64 bit)

```
    typedef struct {
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
        struct {
            int ab;
            long bc;
        }
        int d;
    } Test;

I see that,
a = 4 bytes
b = 4 bytes
c = 4 bytes
padding1 = 4 bytes 
inner structure = 16 bytes ( 4 bytes for ab, 4 bytes padding, 8 bytes for bc)
d = 4 bytes
padding2 = 4 bytes
```

sizeof(Test) returns 40 bytes.

My questions:

1. padding1 -> why is this 4 bytes? Is this because the inner structure itself should be aligned ?. ( Also, Is it aligned with 8 byte (long) or 16 byte (size of inner) boundary.? )
2. padding2 -> Is this 4 byte padding because of max of alignment done inside the structure (which is 8)  ??

Thanks,

Comment: You code doesn't compile. Please only post real compiled code that has been verified to produce the claimed results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1. padding1 -> why is this 4 bytes? Is this because the inner structure itself should be aligned ?. ( Also, Is it aligned with 8 byte (long) or 16 byte (size of inner) boundary.? )

It's because the inner `struct` should be 8-byte aligned, so that the `long` can reliably be 8-byte aligned.

> 1. padding2 -> Is this 4 byte padding because of max of alignment done inside the structure (which is eight) ??

It is there so that the size of the entire `struct` is a multiple of eight bytes, so that the inner `struct` can be suitably aligned on an eight-byte boundary.

In this particular case, the alignment requirements could be met with just four bytes of padding if an anonymous `struct` member could be treated differently from a free-standing `struct`, but 6.7.2.1

> 14 Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in an implementation-defined manner appropriate to its type.

forbids that. So to reduce the size of the `struct`, the programmer needs to rearrange it, move an odd number of `int` members past the inner `struct` (or make `int ab;` and `long bc;` direct members of `Test` without going through an anonymous `struct`).

Comment: "the alignment requirements could be met with just four bytes of padding" -- No, they couldn't. Any struct containing `bc` must have the same alignment, so both the inner struct and outer struct must be long-aligned, requiring padding for `c`, `ab`, and `d`.

Comment: It's an anonymous struct, it never leaves the enclosing struct. Since you can't have any freestanding exemplars of it, why shouldn't the compiler treat them as separate direct members of the enclosing struct for layout purposes?

Comment: Aren't fields guaranteed to have strictly increasing addresses?

Comment: @AlanStokes Yes, that's one of the few guarantees the standard makes about the layout. The "one" who could move the `d` member is the programmer, not the compiler.

Comment: @DanielFischer, anonymous or not shouldn't influence on the layout. The layout must be the same between different compilation units, even if the fields are named differently.

Comment: There are no anonymous structs in C, even if some compilers support them. and we don't know if this is an anonymous struct because there's a syntax error ... a name may have been left out along with the semicolon.

Comment: @JimBalter They have been officially added in last year's revision of the standard - unless they have been removed between n1570 and the release of the standard, but I expect I'd have heard about that. (I didn't notice the missing semicolon, though.)

Comment: I missed that they have been added. Odd, because unlike anonymous unions, anonymous structs aren't useful. I'll have to study the C standard to understand the alignment issues, but I would be surprised if they are different between named and unnamed structs.

Comment: @JimBalter I don't see the usefulness either [for structs, anonymous unions are obviously useful]. From my scanning of n1570, I think now that indeed anonymous structs must be treated like named structs regarding alignment and padding - although, since the members of anonymous structs are [considered to be] members of the enclosing struct [recursively], and they cannot escape, it would make sense to treat them directly as members of the enclosing struct for these purposes.

Comment: It would have made even more sense not to add something useless (or worse; not only do anonymous structs add useless syntactic noise, they make structs bigger for no reason) to the standard. Whether the OP was asking about the padding imposed by this useless misfeature is still a mystery.

Comment: I retract my comments about uselessness, because *tagged* anonymous structs are useful, and disallowing untagged anonymous structs would make the language and implementations more complex ... as would having different alignment requirements for them, so I'm glad to hear that's not the case. Which brings me back to my original comment: all 12 bytes of padding are necessary.

Comment: But "An unnamed member whose type specifier is a structure specifier **with no tag** is called an _anonymous structure_;" (bold is mine) if I understand correctly, there are no _tagged_ anonymous structs. Regarding the original comment, @Jim, yes, and I have edited to that effect yesterday.

Comment: Ok, I made a terminological error, but I think the semantics are right. But enough chit-chat. Thanks for making the correction.

Comment: @JimBalter I apologise if it came over as if I was rubbing it in, that was not the intention. If I could have an unnamed member in the struct whose type was a tagged struct, that would be useful. But I don't think that is allowed, the only mentions of unnamed mebers I'm aware of are bitfields and anonymous structs/unions. If what I think you meant with tagged anonymous structs are allowed, I'd be thankful to learn about that.

Comment: It didn't come over that way at all. And I wrote off the top of my head; if the Standard allows useless unnamed untagged structs but not useful unnamed tagged structs then the committee has been taken over by imbeciles. I'll investigate when I get the time.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is very platform and compiler dependent, even though the behaviour you see is very common.

In general (and this is not what the C standard says), the compiler aligns the members of a structure so as to reduce the number of memory accesses. In case of 64-bit x86, a memory access always fetches 8 bytes, aligned to the 64-bit boundary. In other words, if you access 1 byte at address *0x1010AA45*, the CPU will actually fetch from (cache) memory 8 bytes at address *0x01010AA40*.

In order to fulfil such rule, if a member is N byte long, the compiler typically rounds N to the next power of 2, and aligns the member to such size or 8 bytes on 64-bit platforms, whatever is smaller. Most compilers allow such rule to be tweaked though, via `#pragma` or configuration.

I believe your compiler adds *Padding1* because it has a rule to align all structures to the 8 byte boundary, no matter how big they are. Alternatively, it could also introduce it because the inner structure is larger than 4 bytes, and it therefore needs to be aligned to 8 bytes.

*Padding2* is probably introduced because you could make an array of `struct Test`. In order, to guarantee that all structures are correctly aligned to the 8 byte boundary - and not just the first item in the array - the padding at the end is defined.

Comment: Given that the implementation aligns longs on 8-byte boundaries, all the padding is required by the C Standard ... both `a` and `ab` must be at offset 0 of the structs containing them, forcing 4 bytes after `ab` and after either `a`, `b`, or `c`, and there must be padding either before or after `d` for array element alignment.